# Change precision on geometry operations in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeometry

Is it possible to change/define precision on/for geometry operations like `STEquals`, `STUnion`, ...? More concrete... let say we have to geometries in Web Mercator coordinate system (3857) where I want to have precision, let's say, on 1 decimal number.

```
DECLARE @g1 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 3857); 
DECLARE @g2 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180.0001)', 3857); 

Select @g1.STEquals(@g2)
-- returns 0/false
```

It there a way to manipulate those functions so `STEquals` would return 1/true ?

Comment: Probably not, but maybe something functionally equivalent (no pun intended). What about `Select @g1.STBuffer(0.05).STContains(@g2)`?

Comment: I think index won't work in this case if @g1 is a value in the table...

Comment: Nothing in your question says one or the other of the values is in a table. That said, you're right. But! You should be able to flip the comparison and still have it work.

Comment: I agree with you, I should mention it. But still, I would like to hear like some "global", database-wise or table-wise solution, because it there would exist something like that, than I could sistematically prevent creating geometry like `LINESTRING (100 100, 100 100.0001)` which is topologically incorrect because of precision model.  I have a feeling I will not get it and I will need to implement something by myself.

Comment: Sure. What I'm saying is that if `@g1` is in reality the table side of your comparison and `@g2` is a value you are considering inserting, change the comparison that I suggested to `@g2.STBuffer(0.05).STContains(@g1)`. That's a classic SARG-ability trick, which is to do any calculations on the scalar side of the comparison. In this case, that comparison should be able to use the spatial index on the table.